# Alternative to mCallouts that runs on Premiere?

Tags: premiere, animation, plugins

I'm looking for an alternative for a plugin called [mCallouts](https://www.motionvfx.com/mplugs-111.html) for FCPX that has similar functions that I can use on Premiere.

Is there such thing or do I have to use a Dynamic Link from After Effects to Premiere Pro?

Comment: Call out titles is a good alternative for mCallouts that works for premiere pro